# Pokemon Go isn't compatible with Samsung Galaxy S4 any more?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I just factory reset my phone and updated everything (including Google Play Services) on my Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.

I have been playing the game on this phone for months but now I cannot re-download it, with the Google Play store saying my phone isn't compatible with this version.

What happened?

Comment: No proof, so not an answer: Very likely it was updated with a new version of the SDK, which requires a higher version of Android than 4.4.  When I owned my Note II (stuck at 4.3), this happened pretty commonly to me.  (Including my bank's software, which was aggravating)  If you're okay with rooting the phone, you can find a non-official OS and it may install, but no guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what happened originally, but it's a bit of a moot point now: As of July 2019, Niantic has updated their supported devices and operating systems, dropping support for Android v4 (Kitkat) ([Twitter Announcement](https://twitter.com/NianticHelp/status/1140710740443193344), [Support Article](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=account-and-sign-in&f=discontinued-support-for-android-4-kitkat&p=web)), as well as iOS 9 ([Support](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=account-and-sign-in&f=discontinued-support-for-ios-9&p=web)), and the Apple Watch ([Support](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=account-and-sign-in&f=discontinued-support-for-apple-watch&p=web)):

The currently supported technical specifications are as follows:

> #### Android
>
> - Android 5 or above
> - Preferred resolution of 720 x 1280 pixels (Not optimized for tablet)
> - Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
> - GPS and Location Services
> - Rooted devices are not supported
>
> #### iOS
>
> - iPhone 5s or above
> - iOS 10 or above
> - Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
> - GPS and Location Services
> - Jailbroken devices are not supported

See Niantic's '[Supported Devices](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=troubleshooting&f=supported-devices)' Page for more information.